# Parse XML feed in PHP and return it to DOM throwing syntax error

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, xml

I have an application which i'm making an API call to via AJAX. I need to do a cross origin request here using jsonp as shown in my javascript below:

```
    $.ajax({  
        type: "GET",  
        dataType: "jsonp",  
        url: "http://127.0.0.1/edsa-EE%20Dashboard/commentsRequest.php",    
        success: function(data){
           console.log(data)
        }
    })
```

The commentsRequest.php file then makes the XML call and retrieves the data no problem. Here is the code in that file:

```
<?php


    $feed = file_get_contents('https://user:pass@myapi.com/display/?&some_data=2&some_other_data=2');

   $xml=simplexml_load_string($feed) or die("Error: Cannot create object");

    print_r($xml);



?>
```

As you can see i use simplexml_load_string to parse the XML as this was what was recommended online. If I go to http://127.0.0.1/edsa-EE%20Dashboard/commentsRequest.php in my browser I see the data no problem but if I try and retrieve the data into my application via the AJAX call above I get an

> Unexpected identifier

error.

I tried encoding the data as JSON using json_encode($xml) as I thought this may have been the issue and that gave me a slightly different error:

> Unexpected token :

I'm not sure why I am getting these errors after retrieving the data from the server successfully and even encoding it as json.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: what you seeing after ajax call complete in console.log ?

Comment: You cannot parse xml using jsonp. I think you need to transform `$xml` contents into json – unsure if you can achieve it just by `json_encode`-ing it.

Comment: the console.log shows the errors listed above. @m4grio what would you suggest as an alternative to json_encode?

Comment: Don't really need to look for an alternative to json_encode, what you need to revise is whether $xml is _ready_ to be encoded in the way you expect the data to be retrieved or else you need to process/clean it before encoding.